# Communication between DLP2000 Projector Kit and Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi4, texas-instruments, projector

I have a problem with the connection and communication between DLP2000 Projector Kit and Raspberry Pi 4.  I hope someone else other than me would benefit from this post in the future as well. Here is the detailed definition of my problem.

I connected a jumper wire set to its relevant datasheet. After that, I set up the appropriate software. Everythıng seems alright but the projector gives only its default image, not the expected Raspberry screen that I want to see.

I think I have a problem with i2c library.

Any recommendation would be gladly appreciated.

I run ' sudo i2cdetect -y 1 ', this shows no device is connected.

I tried setting up the required library, and got 'Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1′ or` /dev/i2c/1′: No such file or directory'.